# How to get older version on jasperreport -server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I use to get the jasper report server

**jasperreports-server-cp-4.7.0-linux-x64-installer.run** file from

**http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperserver/files**.

But now they have remove it and i cant find it on their website.

Even after 1.5 hours of google still i cant find it.

Can anybody direct me to link or if somebody has it and can share will be great.

Comment: found it guys... if anybody want it let me know

Comment: You may want to answer your own question, especially when you've got the right answer. This is encouraged through the [self-learner badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner).

Comment: i found it in my one of my vm, but not on internet! thats why i have not answer this question

Comment: @Bhuvan I want the older version of jasper reports server v6.4.4 for window 64 bit. Kindly Help!